# Filter & grouping in python reducer

Tags: python, mapreduce

New to Python & map reduce ...

I am having a mapper which generates rows from two table (sorted by user_id)

```
Table_1             Table_2
User_id code        User_id device
123     XYZ         123     TV
123     TRX         123     CD
954     CDF         954     TV
```

Mapper script is generating below in order of (user_id,code,device,table_name)

default value used is -1

```
123^-1^TV^Table_2
123^-1^CD^Table_2    
123^XYZ^-1^Table_1
123^TRX^-1^Table_1
954^-1^TV^Table_1
954^CDF^-1^Table_1
```

Now I want the reducer to give output as (user_id,code,device_cnt)

device count = distinct device per user_id

```
123^XYZ^2
123^TRX^2
954^CDF^1
```

How can I achieve this in Python mapreduce?

Comment: why position of your `-1` is not consistent in your mapper output. its on 2nd column for first two records and in third column in next two?